# Footer comes up in smaller screens

Tags: html, css, footer

I've a html page wherein I display a table with data from the database along with a footer at the bottom of the page.

The problem is that with smaller screens (around less than 760px) the footer, instead of being at the bottom, **goes upwards** and thus **overlaps and hides a portion of the display data**.

I want that irrespective of the screen size, the footer should always be placed at the bottom of the page.

My code snippets are mentioned below. Request you to please provide a solution.

**Edit 1**: A (static) scenario is available at the codepen url (please check out for smaller screen sizes): http://codepen.io/abbor123/pen/YGwVXg

**The footer element**:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Designed & Created by AB </p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-lg fa-creative-commons" aria-hidden="true"></i> Some Rights Reserved </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.footer
{
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 8em;
    margin-top: -5em;
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    background: #009933;
    text-align: center;
}

body
{
    background:url(image.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover; 
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    color: black;
}

@media (max-width: 770px)
{
    #table-display
    {
        font-family: 'Exo 2', serif;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
        text-align: left;
        color: black;
        margin-top: 60px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle...So we can see what's happening? - with a rough guess it's got to be something to do with your css. Look at your `margin-top`

Comment: Yeah its most probably the negative value you have for the margin-top.

Comment: margin-top is not affecting the above scenario. I'll try to create a jsfiddle which may take some time (as the page in question is currently created using data from a database).

Comment: I've created a codepen using dummy data(url is being provided in my original question as an edit). Please note that for smaller screen sizes the footer has come up.

Comment: @ChrisBeckett Please have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the footer problem, remove the `height: 60em;` from the `.row` class. It's at line 68 in the CSS for CodePen. http://codepen.io/FluidOfInsanity/pen/gwvZLN?editors=1100
Also, would you want to remove the `top: 6px;` from the `td:before`? Maybe your example is just a quick mock-up, but it throws off my example.